# Long Exposures of Fireworks. How was this done?

Tags: long-exposure, fireworks

Just saw these amazing [long exposures of fireworks](http://www.daveyjphoto.com/tagged/long-exposure) by Davey J. How did he do that? I'm assuming it's slightly more complicated than just taking a long exposure on a tripod?
[image]